# HTML Select Dropdown ID not passing to Javascript Function getelementbyid value is null

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Novice here, trying to demonstrate the value of client side rest operations to teammates as they rely on scripts and python. Not sure if it's the fact I'm using numbers for the value attribute or if I'm referencing the getelementbyid wrong. It's honestly probably none of those things :)

I've tried to explicitly reference an id assigned to the IP address in the getelementbyid for MakeUrl but it still fails. I also thought for a second it was null becasue it was using the default value but I commented it out and I still got the error.

Error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null (MakUrl Function)

```js
function makeUrl() {
  var ip = document.getElementById("apigatewayip").value;
  return "https://" + ip + "/api/v0/sessions"
};

function createSession(_url) {
  return $.ajax({
    "url": _url,
    "method": "POST",
    "timeout": 0,
    "headers": {
      "Content-Type": "application/json"
    },
    "data": JSON.stringify({
      "gatewayVersion": "1.00.1.15"
    }),
  });
}

createSession(makeUrl());

createSession(makeUrl()).success(function() {

});
```

```html
<h1>Making AJAX Rest Calls</h1>
<div class="custom-select" style="width:200px;">
  <select name="selectip" id="apigatewayip" onchange="makeUrl">
    <option value="" disabled selected>API Gateway IP</option>
    <option value="169.254.1.10">169.254.1.10</option>
  </select>
  <button onclick="createSession">Submit</button>
</div>
```

Comment: The code you've shown works: https://jsfiddle.net/bsrngqm6/. Ensure it's this function causing the error, and that you're not re-using `id` values within the DOM. Also note that `onchange="makeUrl"` is redundant.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan It doesn't, the functions referred in inline handlers are never called ...

Comment: Note that you're calling `createSession` twice in the code here. I'd remove the first call and change the second to use `then` instead of `success`, since `success` has been deprecated.

Comment: @Teemu correct, but they never would be, which is why I mentioned the `onchange` being redundant. The only way OPs code will run is if he calls `makeUrl()` directly, which is what the example does - and it works.

Comment: `$("#apigatewayip").on("change",makeUrl)` or `$("#apigatewayip").on("change",function)( { makeUrl() })` - you are missing the () when you call but which you need to leave out when assigning

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the handlers to call your function, not just assign:

`<button onclick="createSession()">Submit</button>`

Also, you can just create the url in the `createSession` function:

```js
function createSession() {
  var ip = document.getElementById("apigatewayip").value;
  var _url = "https://" + ip + "/api/v0/sessions"
  console.log(_url) // Use this for ajax call
  /*$.ajax({
    "url": _url,
    "method": "POST",
    "timeout": 0,
    "headers": {
      "Content-Type": "application/json"
    },
    "data": JSON.stringify({
      "gatewayVersion": "1.00.1.15"
    }),
  });*/
}
```

```html
<h1>Making AJAX Rest Calls</h1>
<div class="custom-select" style="width:200px;">
  <select name="selectip" id="apigatewayip">
    <option value="" disabled selected>API Gateway IP</option>
    <option value="169.254.1.10">169.254.1.10</option>
  </select>
  <button onclick="createSession()">Submit</button>
</div>
```

Comment: If the `getElementById()` call doesn't work in the OP I don't see how this would address that problem

Comment: Seeing only OP's code its difficult to know how the functions are being called, as you said the `on` handlers are redundant

Comment: I marked this as the answer because it does work. thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Wait for the document to render using document ready `$(function() { })` and use jQuery, don't mix with legacy JavaScript selection

Use `done` callback instead of `success`

```
//Global function 1
function makeUrl() {
    var ip = $("#apigatewayip").val();
    return "https://" + ip + "/api/v0/sessions"
};
//Global function 2
function createSession(_url) {
  return $.ajax({
    "url": _url,
    "method": "POST",
    "timeout": 0,
    "headers": {
      "Content-Type": "application/json"
    },
    "data": JSON.stringify({
      "gatewayVersion": "1.00.1.15"
    }),
  });
}


//Wait until document fully render
$(function() {
   //After document render call the methods
   createSession(makeUrl());

   createSession(makeUrl()).done(function() {

   });
});
```

Comment: Ok, so your code solved my original error, but it is now passing null to the url instead of the selected ip address: "OPTIONS https://null/api/v0/sessions net::ERR_NAME_RESOLUTION_FAILED"

Comment: if that is the case your `<select>` has a different ID or you `<select>` tag does not exits or your `<select>` itself dynamically rendered